# Redirect logged in user using Omniauth in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, omniauth

I've created a login controller so that people can log in using Facebook. When a user logs in he gets routed to `frontpage/show` and when they logout they get redirected to the root_url and it shows the login page.

The problem is that when a user logs in through Facebook, closes the site and then revisits the page he also gets directed to the root_url and not `frontpage/show`.

I've used Omniauth with Rails for this.

This is my session_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to '/frontpage/show'
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_url
  end

end
```

and my frontpage_controller.rb

```
class FrontpageController < ApplicationController
  def show
  end
end
```

I've tried adding

```
def show
  if authenticate_user?
    redirect_to :controller=>'dashboard', :action => 'index'
  else
    redirect_to '/public/example_html_file.html'
  end
end
```

To the frontpage_controller but it gives the error `ndefined method`authenticate_user` which makes sence. But I believe something like this is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i'm assuming that you're using `Devise`. So, you have the method `authenticate_user!` and not `authenticate_user?`.

Now, to check if the user is logged, you can use the `user_signed_in?` instead of `authenticate_user?` and your code should works.

More information about those helper methods here https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers